# /usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory in VSC only

Tags: node.js, bash, ubuntu, nvm, husky

I have a project with a Husky git pre-commit hook:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

yarn lint-staged
```

If I commit from Terminal, the hook and commit work fine.

If I try to commit from VSC, I get error:

```
> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 127 (error)
husky - command not found in PATH=/usr/lib/git-core:/home/myname/.cargo/bin:/home/myname/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
```

So I've been trying to figure out why VSC seems unaware of nvm and where the current node executable is.

My `~/.bashrc` calls `source ~/code/.bashrc_extra`, which includes:

```
echo $0
which bash
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
nvm current
node -v
```

When I open Terminal, I see:

```
bash
/usr/bin/bash
/home/myname/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/bin/node
v18.18.2
v18.18.2
```

So, everything in Terminal is fine, so it makes sense that it works there.

When I open a VSC terminal, I see those same values except `/usr/bin/bash` instead of `bash`.

How can I fix my setup so that the pre-commit hook will work?

- VSC 1.84.2
- Ubuntu 22.04.3

Comment: Can you try to put `source ~/.bashrc` in your pre-commit hook, just under shebang line ?

Comment: Or add the debug messages there. Your ~/.bashrc may just exit for noninteractive sessions. Check it.

Comment: @Philippe Interesting idea to try. It results in `.husky/pre-commit: 2: source: not found` getting printed twice and then `husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 127 (error)
husky - command not found in PATH=`

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Can you please explain? What should I write under `#!/usr/bin/env sh` in the pre-commit file? Thanks.

Comment: Change you shebang line to `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: @Philippe still `/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory` or if I include `source ~/.bashrc` then `.husky/pre-commit: 2: source: not found`. Thanks for your ideas, though.

Comment: Did you do both `#!/usr/bin/env bash` and `source ~/.bashrc` at the same time?

Comment: @Philippe Yes, I tried with both, and I also tried without sourcing `.bashrc`.

Comment: Post you ~/.bashrc to avoid having to guess